# Marker of Google Maps Javascript API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an issue in the Google Maps JS API but probably the JS code problem.

```
var buildingObject = [
    [1, 'Mongkok Commercial Centre', '16 Argyle Street, Mongkok', 'CCCCCC', '75.00'],
    [2, 'Central Government Offices', '2 Tim Mei Ave, Admiralty', '999999', '70.00']
];

function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.352734, 114.1277) // Hong Kong
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    for(i = 0; i < buildingObject.length; i++) {

        // Global Variables
        var addressObject = null;
        var iconLink = null;
        var latLng = null;
        var marker = null;

        iconLink = "//chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_spin&chld=0.6|0|" + encodeURIComponent(buildingObject[i][3]) + "|9|_|" + encodeURIComponent(buildingObject[i][4]);

        $.ajax({
            "url": "//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + encodeURIComponent(buildingObject[i][2]) + "&sensor=false&region=hk&language=en"
        }).done(function(goc) {
            if(goc.results && goc.results.length > 0 && goc.results[0].geometry && goc.results[0].geometry.location) {  
                addressObject = {
                    address:        goc.results[0].formatted_address,
                    coor: {
                        latitude:   goc.results[0].geometry.location.lat,
                        longitude:  goc.results[0].geometry.location.lng
                    },
                };

                latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(addressObject.coor.latitude, addressObject.coor.longitude);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map:        map,
                    position:   latLng,
                    icon:       iconLink,
                    title:      addressObject.address
                });
            }
        });
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I think the code should be fine but it could not give me the expected result so there must be a problem.

As you can see the object has 5 attributes. I want Google Maps do a search and return the Latitude and Longitude and formatted address into addressObject. Then, Google Maps Marker will mark the locations with a iconLink based on the background defined in `buildingObject[3]` and the index in `buildingObject[4]`.

A link will be generated in `iconLink = "//chart ..."` and let the Marker class to pickup.

**The results:**
Marker: Pointed successfully
Background & Index: Showed incorrectly (it will only use the value of the last object data >> 999999 and 70.00)

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dyp5hzh3/

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't show a map.  [updated fiddle (shows map)](http://jsfiddle.net/dyp5hzh3/1/)

Comment: @geocodezip, yeah. I was modifying my code for stackoverflow and I didn't notice that the fiddle didn't show the map. Thank you for your updated fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating the index in your loop before the ajax call has returned, so it will always give you the icon link for the last building.    Updated fiddle to change the structure of the code here http://jsfiddle.net/brendaz/5xpn3m1v/

```
   $.ajax({
      ...
   }).done(function (goc) {
      ...
      getBuildingObject(index + 1);
   }
```